# How to disassemble data type and macros in gdb?

Tags: gdb

```
341 item *item_get(const char *key, const size_t nkey) {
342     item *it;
...
```

I want to disassemble `item` :

```
(gdb) info item
Undefined info command: "item".  Try "help info".
(gdb) disas item
Attempt to use a type name as an expression
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: A word about your terminology: "disassemble" means to take machine instructions in binary form (e.g. `0x58`) and convert them to something we can understand (e.g. `pop %eax`).  So you should only be disassembling functions.  In your examples, `item` is a data type, and `it` is a locally-defined pointer to an object of type `item`.

Answer (score 2):

I generally find that printing a variable ends up with a decent description, assuming GDB can find the headers appropriately.  Try:

```
gdb> p *it
```